# List-style-type and display:inline won't work

Tags: html, css

I've seen a fair amount asked about this in certain areas, but the answers I found didn't resolve my problem. I'm trying to make a nav menu, and can't get the list style set to none, nor will it display inline. Here is the HTML/CSS I had written:

```
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Dream Series</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
}
```

I don't know if it's interfering elements elsewhere on the page, but I tried creating it both inside and outside my header with the same result...which was basically none. I'm wanting to remove the bullet points, center the elements and/or add padding between them, and style the text with the font on the res tof the page, but after getting the element to appear, any stylization I add via CSS isn't applying.

I'm editing because apparently the post was labelled 'off-topic', so I reworded the above text a bit. Also wanted to point out I'm not using embedded css, I'm applying it from an external .css file, which has cooperated just fine until this issue. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/qvmtx29s/

Comment: @cocoa he missed the <style> tag... in your fiddle you must have copy pasted the css in to it's box

Answer (score 1):

Your css is correct. However, did you enter the code exactly the way you display it above?? Your css needs to go inside a `<style>` tag if you want it on the same file as your markup. Like so:

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dream Series</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<style>
.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
}
</style>
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/sutn1y93/)

Answer (score 0):

What you have written above should work.

I took your code and plugged it in fiddle and it displayed just fine.

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Dream Series</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

.nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li {
display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uL3sonrx/1/

You must have something affecting it in your css. Try inspecting it through Firebug or Chrome developer tools to see all the styles applied to it.